# jQuery Wait for select to populate from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have ddl(drop down list) which populates from database after change event of another ddl but I want to change the value of this ddl after it populated from database.

Example:

```
// This work very well
$("#ddlGroups").on('change',function(){
    // Load data from database and populate ddlUsers
    // response is loaded from database with $.ajax
    // Query Example: SELECT User_ID, Username FROM tblUsers WHERE Group_ID = [Group_ID] (Just for undrestanding the question)

    var Records = response.d;
    $("#ddlUsers").empty();
    $.each(Records, function(){
    var _Key = this.User_ID;
        _Value = this.Username;
        $("#ddlUsers").append($("<option />").val(_Key).text(_Value));
    });
});

// When button clicked then trigger ddlGroups change event and assign select option from ddlUsers
var _UserID = User_ID_From_Database; // Loaded from Database when button clicked
$("#ddlGroups").trigger('change'); // Users are loaded from database based on group ID
$("#ddlUsers").val(_UserID); // But this dosn't change
```

How do I check if ddlUsers is loaded or not, I tried while loop but it never stops.

Comment: Can you be more clear? Maybe show us more code?

Comment: Changed all question.

Comment: I presume you mean [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) rather than [`tigger`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigger).

Comment: That is not the problem it works fine.

Comment: You can check the length of the options: `$("#ddlUsers option").length`

Comment: @tymeJV, but it takes time to load from database it passes the line `$("#ddlUsers").val(_UserID);`

Comment: I dont see an AJAX call? You have to post that as well, I see the comments for it.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery there are two main ways (really the same underlying) to connect a ajax response from the database to a event or UI result.  The first is promises and the second is a callback.  Both these have 1 million examples and jquery documentation is quite robust.

In your case rather than "trigger", you callback calls the right function.  The below is just junk code to show.

```
No:  $("#ddlGroups").tigger('change'); 

Yes:
//Your code 
$("#ddlGroups").on('change', updateDDL);

//I have just externalized this function to a scope/place where both the ajax and on change line of code can reference it.
function updateDDL(){

    var Records = response.d;
    $("#ddlUsers").empty();
    $.each(Records, function(){
    var _Key = this.User_ID;
        _Value = this.Username;
        $("#ddlUsers").append($("<option />").val(_Key).text(_Value));
    }
};

$.ajax(...., function (data) {
// Update ddl, the existing function you have.
// You should already have something like this.
updateDDL();  //Like this
});
```

BTW: You could pass the data into the updateDDL directly use $(this) in the updateDDL to improve it etc but that is not key to your question/issue.  It seems that you are new to jquery and some of the Javascript features it uses.  Take a little time to learn about them and you will be WELL rewarded.  I would start by reading examples around ajax/jquery and watch how then update the DOM.